# Is it possible to run a Lightning Network node with multiple entities holding parts of the private key?

Tags: lightning-network, hash-time-locked-contract, key-aggregation

What's the technical limitation stopping multiple entities from collectively managing an LN node?

I understand all parties (entities that share the Node private key) need to be online to sign routing/sending/creating invoices. If we assume this is the case and they're queried by a simple API for their signature for each such action, is there another technical limitation to why pooled/combined/shared nodes like this can not exist?

The use case is to have multiple parties contribute funds and run a larger LN node with more liquidity.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you would have to write custom code. But other than that I don't see any reason why this should not be possible. Actually there come quite some architectures and technologies in my mind that would nicely enable such functionality.